# Im confused over sulfur's ability to form 4 bonds

Tags: valence-bond-theory

I'm a High School AP Chemistry student, and I am still confused on sulfur. I understand why it can form $2$ bonds to complete its outer shell, but when I was drawing a Lewis structure for Thiosulfite ($\ce{S2O2^{2-}}$), I drew it as (O-)-S-S-(O-). This seemed to work out perfectly, as the oxygens had each a minus 1 charge, and therefore only needed one bond. However, when I looked online, I saw a sulfur double bonded to another, and also bonded to two oxygen anions. This confounded me, as I saw the sulfur with 4 bonds! I did some research, and I found that the reason for this was that sulfur had vacant d orbitals. When I asked my teacher about this, she told me that it sulfur did NOT have vacant d orbitals. I went deeper down the rabbit hole, and found that there was a debate over vacant d orbitals even existing in the first place! What is the true answer, or the most likely answer to this question? Thank you!

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiosulfurous_acid

Comment: You are drawing dead, at least for now. Thiosulfites and the parent thiosulfurous acid are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Sulphur has electronic configuration :
1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p4
The 3 shell has 3 sub-shells namely s,p and d (having azimuthal quantum numbers 0,1 and 2)
Thus the more accurate configuration would be :
1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p4 3d0
The energy difference between the 3s and 3d and the 3p and 3d sub-shell is low enough to allow 1 paired electron to ‘excite’ to the 3d sub-shell where it would become unpaired (and available for covalent bonding)
As there are two paired electrons (1 in 3s and 1 in 3p sub-shells), sulphur can form 4 and even 6 covalent bonds, as seen in SF6